# Error accessing classList on return value from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a div that looks like:

```
<div class="wrapper transform-class">
</div>
```

and in my css I have some css transform. So my `transform-class` has:

```
-webkit-transform: none !important;
```

Then of course, my wrapper has the transform styles on there.

So once the page has loaded, after a few seconds. I remove the `transform-class` and then the styles for the `wrapper` class take over and it has a nice bit of animation.

I don't want to use jQuery (i'm trying to learn more/better JavaScript). I'm getting

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`

as my JavaScript error.. my JS file looks like:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
      el.classList.remove("transform-class");
}, 2000);
```

any ideas?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array and not just a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**getElementsByClassName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Therefore, access a specific item by index, then use remove

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
  for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
      els[i].classList.remove("transform-class");
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: and if you want to remove the class from all of the .wrapper elements, then just loop over the array, and remove it for each element.

Comment: @dangor, good suggestion, thanks

Comment: @ Snoopies: Note that `classList` is relatively new and [may not be supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) on all of your target browsers. If not, [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript?lq=1) show you how to use `className` instead. (For that matter, `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported on IE8, which sadly still has a significant market share. Consider `querySelectorAll` instead.)

Comment: Thank you! & thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware I needed to pass in the index

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, a valid point, especially to those(me included) who are trying to learn vanilla javascript. Thanks for your input